# Why am I getting an error in my main program that says: No instance of constructor matches argument list?

Tags: c++

*I am getting an error in my main program that is not recognizing my constructor. What am I doing wrong?*

Passing of argument to constructor in Main function:

`Vehicle aVehicle("VVV-111", 2010);`

Constructor Defintion:

```
Vehicle::Vehicle(char p[], int y) {

  strcpy(this->plateNum, p);
  this->year = y;
  this->Address[64]= "Factory"}
```

Vehicle class

```
      class Vehicle {

      char plateNum [9];
      const char* Address[64];
      int year;

   public:
      Vehicle();
      ~Vehicle();
      Vehicle(char p[], int y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a string literal, which is of type `const char[8]` (8 for the size of the string literal), to a function receiving `char []`, which is equivalent to receiving a `char *` (because C arrays decay to pointers across function boundaries).

If you make the constructor receive a `const char *` (or `const char[]`), it should work.

However, I've no idea what you mean by `this->Address[64]= "Factory"`. That line makes no sense.

Comment: Technically speaking: 1) function arguments of type `const char*`, and `const char[]` are equivalent. So, one wouldn't need to change it to `const char*` One would need to just add a `const` to an existing argument type. 2) String literal `"VVV-111"` has a type of `const char[8]`, not `const char*` (if you assume that it is `const char*`, you might run into unexpected behavior, when trying to write template specializations for string literals).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks for the clarifications, I edited to correct for those.

Comment: @katarachan No problem, you're welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow. If an answer solved your issue, it is customary to accept it.

Comment: This is awesome. I just got my answer so fast.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling your method you should send same datatype to method's parameter,
for example you can change your constructor calling as below :

```
char p[9];
strcpy(p, "VVV-111");
Vehicle aVehicle(p, 2010);
```